# How can I make my Ubuntu 12.04 look like a Mac? 

Tags: 12.04, themes

I want my Ubuntu to look like Mac OS X. Just icon and theme if possible! Is it possible? Is there any way to install slingshot launcher?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a OS X Lion theme for Precise and other versions available in the [Noobslab themes PPA](https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/themes).

**The full blog post on Noobslab about changing the cursors, installing Cairo Dock for a "OS X"-ish launcher and other ways to max out the OS X feeling like a Apple splash screen can be found [here](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/05/mac-os-x-lion-for-ubuntu-1204-precise.html).**

---

**In short (for 12.04)**: you have to add the repository to you sources and install the packages then. To do that open a terminal and enter these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mac-os-lion-theme mac-os-lion-cursors mac-os-lion-icons
```

To change your theme, icons and cursors you must use a tool. You can install one like that (again: from a terminal):

```
## for Gnome Tweak Tool
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool

## for Ubuntu Tweak
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

---

**As for Slingshot launcher:** there is no stable release yet! You could add the elementary-dev/daily PPA and install a unstable version but that bears a high risk for your system!

Maybe (and just maybe since I don't know if this will work) you could download the latest stable version of slingshot [here](https://launchpad.net/slingshot) and install it manually: [How to install tar.gz](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-107338-how-to-install-tar-gz-file-on-ubuntu)

Comment: I think they changed the package names recently. I've corrected that now. If installing `mac-os-lion-theme`, `mac-os-lion-icons` and `mac-os-lion-cursors` fails, please let me know!

Answer (score 7):

Here is another way...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/themes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install adwaita-cupertino-gtk-theme
```

This will install the theme. Here is a description for the theme from the WebUpd8 website:

> Mac-like GTK3 theme in two variants, each optimized for either GNOME
>   Shell or unity Package name: “adwaita-cupertino-gtk-theme”
>
> Ubuntu versions: 12.04, 11.10"