# How to install mac os theme for Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, themes, gnome-classic, macosx, macbuntu

How to install Mac OS theme in Ubuntu 14.04 ? I searched all of Google but no proper results on Mac OS theme for Ubuntu all i get is Mac-buntu which has unity 
and doesn't look like mac at all . Help me  i want to get mac theme in my Ubuntu
as i cannot install mac on PC

Comment: Similar or the same? http://askubuntu.com/questions/132521/how-can-i-make-my-ubuntu-12-04-look-like-a-mac?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

Just follow this guide - http://www.noobslab.com/2014/04/macbuntu-1404-pack-is-released.html it shows more than just the Macbuntu theme, including the login screen, Mac OS X in top left corner, etc.